# Adding date related constraints on table columns with specific conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Below is the following table I have created:

```
CREATE Screening_Plan
(
 plan_id NUMBER (4) PRIMARY KEY,
 movie_id NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
 plan_start_date DATE NOT NULL,
 plan_end_date DATE NOT NULL,
 plan_min_start_hh24 NUMBER (2) NOT NULL,
 plan_max_start_hh24 NUMBER (2) NOT NULL,
 plan_no_of_screenings NUMBER (2) NOT NULL
);
```

For plan_start_date column, how to add a constraint to default: next Monday ?

For plan_end_date column, how to add a constraint to default: next Monday + 6(days) ?

For plan_min_start_hh24 column, how to add a constraint to keep value between 9(9:00 am) and 22(10:00 pm) and set default value to 9 ?

For plan_max_start_hh24 column, how to add a constraint to keep value between 9(9:00 am) and 22(10:00 pm) and set default value to 22 and set greater than or equal to plan_min_start_hh24 ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to add these rules as constraints at table-level?  In my experience this sort of logic is coded at the application layer

Comment: I actually wanted to test out and see regarding how constraints work at the table-level just for knowledge.

Comment: Do you want to assing a DEFAULT value to a column to be assigned to that column if a an INSERT statement omits a value for this column ? Or you want to define an INTEGRITY CONSTRAINT, that is a rule which prohibits from storing in the column the values that don't meet dfined condition ? There are two separate things - DEFAULT and CONSTRAINT. In the latter case a constraint like `start date must be NEXT MONDAY` doesn't makes sense.

Comment: You can try to read some documents on how constraints works. Example https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/clauses002.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints in Oracle cannot reference anything non-deterministic, i.e., an expression whose result can/will change over time. This means that you cannot use a constraint to enforce things like "next Monday". In general, constraints must be true or false regardless of when they are evaluated. See [Restrictions on Check Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm).

This could, however, be done as a trigger on that table.

As for the other constraints, something like this should work:

```
alter table Screening_Plan add constraint Screening_Plan_ck1 check (
  plan_min_start_hh24 between 9 and 22
);

alter table Screening_Plan modify(plan_min_start_hh24 number(2) not null default 9);
```